# Wrong decimal code while trying to convert emoji to decimal

Tags: php

I want to get from emoji his decimal code, so I have this code: (from one of forum threads)

```
$utf32 = mb_convert_encoding( "❤️", 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8' );
$hex4 = bin2hex($utf32);
$dec = hexdec($hex4);
echo "&amp;#$dec;";
echo $output;
```

its work fine, but not with all emojis, for example with this emoji - its return me this decimal code: `&#43310450277903;`
 that its absolutly not the true decimal, any suggestion to this code?

Comment: Please help.. its urgent!

Comment: having the same issue...were you able to resolve?